# Free Flex Drag and Drop IDE

Tags: user-interface, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, ide, mxml

Does anyone know if there are any free IDE's for Flex Development that allow you to drag and drop components from a toolbox?

I have tried to download Tofino created by Ensemble but this product does not feature on their product list anymore.
I have also tried to download Amethyst 2 by Saffire Software from their website but all links for any of the three different visual studio versions don't seem to work.

Can someone please provide an alternative download link for these products or suggest some different products.

Comment: FYI, stackoverflow tries to discourage "recommend a download for me" type questions.  As for IDEs, I can't help on that point -- I just use FlashBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You should try posting this on [StackExchange Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I haven't gotten around to using it, but you might want to look at [Moonshine IDE](http://moonshine-ide.com/), which is currently being developed. It has the ability to help you create MXML with a drag-and-drop editor.